# C# MVC Handle compilation error in views e.g. missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My question is regarding handling errors like "missing an assembly reference?" in views specifically layout.cshtml

e.g. if I have some code in Head tag in layout.cshtml

```
<head>

@{
  @{

        try
        {
            var EnableSomething = BusinessLogic.MyBLL.GetSetting("SettingName");
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

</head>
```

This will work properly, but what if someone came and change "MyBLL" to "MyBLL1", in Layout.cshtml or remove the BusinessLogic DLL or change the DLL in a way that "MyBLL" does not exist in that DLL.

If there a way to handle this kind of situation in layout.cshtml itself ?
I know this is a strange situation but just wanted to know if there is any way to handle this kind of situation.

Thank you all.

Comment: That code belongs in your controller, not a view.

Comment: MyBLL is class?
BusinessLogic is namespace?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right, this code should be in controller but in this case it is in view ( layout.cshtml ). and it gives the compilation error when anyone request the page in above situation.

Comment: @daniel.shih yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Deepak you already know what your problem is. The code is, where it should not be. Move it and get compile time errors. Pass the information into the view using a viewmodel or ViewData

Comment: @Marco you are right, and i am working on moving the code from view, but in the mean time i wanted to know if there is any way to handle this kind of error in view itself.

Comment: I know it's late but for anyone who is wondering how I solved this is, to move the code in controller and get a viewdata/viewbag which will have either setting value or null, so there won't be any exception which i cannot handle at view level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and install the Nuget of [RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator)

It will cause the build to break if building a view fails , So in the case of "MyBLL" to "MyBLL1"